# How to correctly call function with standard arguments, *args and **kwargs

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
def ar4(val1, val2, *args, **kwargs):
    print(val1)
    print(val2)
    print(args)
    print(kwargs)
    
ar4(val1=100, val2=200, "a", "b", "c", k1=1, k2=2, k3="Three", k4=True)
```

In function call `val1=100, val2=200` are for standard arguments, `"a", "b", "c"` are for args and `k1=1, k2=2, k3="Three", k4=True` for kwargs.

It produces error:

```
  Cell In[28], line 7
    ar4(val1=100, val2=200, "a", "b", "c", k1=1, k2=2, k3="Three", k4=True)
                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

This works well:

```
def ar4(val1, val2, *args, **kwargs):
    print(val1)
    print(val2)
    print(args)
    print(kwargs)
    
ar4(100, 200, "a", "b", "c", k1=1, k2=2, k3="Three", k4=True)
```

but I want to pass `val1` and `val2` in a form `val1=100, val2=200` and not just `100, 200`

**Question:** How to correct my code above so I can call function with standard arguments with argument names provided to function call, args and kwargs at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key-word arguments (`kwargs`) come after positional `arg`uments, whether specified by `**kwargs` or variable names (e.g. `val1`, `val2`):

```
def ar4(*args, val1, val2, **kwargs):
    print(val1)
    print(val2)
    print(args)
    print(kwargs)
    
ar4("a", "b", "c", val1=100, val2=200, k1=1, k2=2, k3="Three", k4=True)
```

Outputs:

```
100
200
('a', 'b', 'c')
{'k1': 1, 'k2': 2, 'k3': 'Three', 'k4': True}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a special reason you need to pass the arguments as `val1=100` each time? If you label it as 'val1' and 'val2' in the original function definition, what ever values you pass to the function will be labeled as val1 and val2 inside of that function as you have already provided the variable name to the function in the definition.

For example:

```
def ar4(val1, val2, *args, **kwargs):
    print(val1)
    print(val2)


ar4(100, 200, "a", "b", "c", k1=1, k2=2, k3="Three", k4=True)
```

would output:

```
100
200
```

I hope I understood you question properly.